# Связь между слоями и объектами (Object model, DAO, DTO, Services)

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, инспекция-кода

Код: https://github.com/Dermenji/WeatherOOP/tree/master/src/com/sirma

Цель: создание модели объектов, слои (DAO, DTO) сервисы.

Прошу о инспекции кода - советы по организации и структуре. Связь между слоями и объектами. Вопрос задал как проверку проделаной работы после того как получил наставления в предыщем своем вопросе - [DTO слой имплементация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549061/dto-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/549081?noredirect=1#comment707203_549081)

Назначение кода: практика ООП. Задание по сбору данных с метеостанции (города) по факторам(температура, влажность, скорость и направление ветра, у каждого фактора своя единица измерения). Хранение данных в коллекции.

Реализация методов не требуется, только совету по структуре проекта, ООП, может и патерны проектирования.

Общий абстрактный класс:

```
public abstract class Measurements {

    private Date date;
    private City city;
    private Rainfall rainfall;
    private Temperature temp;
    private AirHumidity airHumidity;
    private WindSpeed windSpeed;
    private Wind wind;

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public City getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(City city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public Rainfall getRainfall() {
        return rainfall;
    }

    public WindSpeed getWindSpeed() {
        return windSpeed;
    }

    public void setWindSpeed(WindSpeed windSpeed) {
        this.windSpeed = windSpeed;
    }

    public void setRainfall(Rainfall rainfall) {
        this.rainfall = rainfall;
    }

    public Temperature getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public void setTemp(Temperature temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public AirHumidity getAirHumidity() {
        return airHumidity;
    }

    public void setAirHumidity(AirHumidity airHumidity) {
        this.airHumidity = airHumidity;
    }

    public Wind getWindDirection() {
        return wind;
    }

    public void setWindDirection(Wind wind) {
        this.wind = wind;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Measurements{" +
                "date=" + date +
                ", city=" + city +
                ", rainfall=" + rainfall +
                ", temp=" + temp +
                ", airHumidity=" + airHumidity +
                ", windSpeed=" + windSpeed +
                ", windDirection=" + wind +
                '}';
    }
}

public interface MeasurmentsDAO {

    List<MeasurmentsDTO> getAll();

    MeasurmentsDTO update(MeasurmentsDTO entity);

    MeasurmentsDTO add(MeasurmentsDTO entity);

    MeasurmentsDTO getByName(MeasurmentsDTO name);
}

public interface MeasurmentsDTO {
    Date getDate();

    void setDate(Date date);

    City getCity();

    void setCity(City city);

    Rainfall getRainfall();

    WindSpeed getWindSpeed();

    void setWindSpeed(WindSpeed windSpeed);

    void setRainfall(Rainfall rainfall);

    Temperature getTemp();

    void setTemp(Temperature temp);

    AirHumidity getAirHumidity();

    void setAirHumidity(AirHumidity airHumidity);

    Wind getWindDirection();

    void setWindDirection(Wind wind);
}
```

Пример с фактором температуры:

```
public class Temperature extends Measurements {
    private int value;
    private final static String unit = Units.TEMP.value();

    public Temperature(int value, String unit) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Temperature{" +
                "value=" + value +
                ", type='" + unit + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

public interface TemperatureDAO {
    List<TemperatureDTO> getAll();

    void addTemperature(TemperatureDTO temperature);

    void deleteTemperature(TemperatureDTO temperature);
}
public interface TemperatureDTO {
    String getUnit();

    int getValue();

    void setValue(int value);
}
```

Comment: У вас в чистом виде Anemic Domain Model. Ну а за отсутствие конкретики в самом вопросе - от меня минус (и голос за закрытие).

Comment: В моем предыдушем вопросе попросили создать отдельный вопрос. - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549061/dto-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/549081?noredirect=1#comment707203_549081Минус так минус.
Вопрос мой о правильной связи между слоями DAO, DTO и объектами.
Задание подразумеваес сбор входящих данных с метеостанций городов всех факторов - темепратура влажность ветра и т.д.

Comment: @АлександрДерменжи, ознакомьтесь с [требованиями к вопросам по инспекции кода](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1761/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-code-review). На данный момент, вопрос им не соответствует

Comment: Инспектируемый код должен быть _непосредственно_ в вопросе, ссылка может служить лишь дополнением

Comment: Получится слишком объемно по моему мнению если все классы вставлю в вопрос.

Comment: @АлександрДерменжи у вас дао немного не так реализован. у вас должен быть абстрактный контроллер для основных функции: getAll(), add, update, delete, find... а вы для каждого класса создаете свой интерфейс с этими функциями.  это копипаст кода. сделаете абстрактный класс и наследутесь от него. писал об этом в первом вопросе. тоже самое про интерфейсы ДТО. `getValue() void setValue(int value);` все время повторяются. сделаете общий интерфейс