# Оптимизируем кода на JAVA

Tags: java, оптимизация

Задача состоит в следующем:

Shape класс обеспечивает метод draw (...) ... для рисования фигур. Переместите метод draw (...) к Rectangle класса. Пожалуйста предложите другие решения для улучшения качества кода

```
public class Shape {
    private String title;
    //Other fields, constructors, get, set, etc.

    public Shape(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    private void draw(Graphics graphics, Rectangle rectangle) {
        rectangle.setVisible(false);
        graphics.setColor(rectangle.getColor());
        graphics.drawLine(rectangle.getX1(),rectangle.getY1(),rectangle.getX2(),rectangle.getY2());
        //Other code
        rectangle.setVisible(true);
    }
}


public class Rectangle{
    private int x1, y1;
    private int x2, y2;
    private Color color;
    private boolean visible;
    //Othre fields, constructors, get, set, etc


    public Rectangle(String title, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color color, boolean visible) {
        super(title);
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y2;
        this.color = color;
        this.visible = visible;
    }

    public int getX1() {
        return x1;
    }

    public int getY1() {
        return y1;
    }

    public int getX2() {
        return x2;
    }

    public int getY2() {
        return y2;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public boolean getVisible() {
        return visible;
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
    }
}
```

Такую задачу дал мне интервьюер

По моему мнению если я перенесу метод draw () до Rectangle класса, то можно будет с этого метода забрать параметр "Rectangle rectangle" и использовать методы не так "rectangle.setVisible (false)" а так "setVisible (false)"

Что еще здесь еще можно улучшить?

Comment: я бы добавил интерфейс Drawable, в котором был бы метод draw и затем имплементировал бы его в Rectangle

Comment: Почитайте про наследование, полиморфизм, инкапсуляция. То, что вы хотите сделать, как мне кажется, не то что хочет увидеть от вас интервьюер.

Comment: Я бы отказался от такого конструктора "угадайки", в нём слишком много параметров, так же ввел более осмысленные название переменных - про иксы игрики то понятно на вкус все фломастеры разные; а вот переменная `color` не дает о себе не какой информации, это цвет фона или же цветы внутреннего шрифта?

Comment: @Komdosh зачем создавать интерфейс для одного класса? А с Shape его не получится использовать, потому что входные параметры разные - там не нужен Rectangle

Comment: "По моему мнению если я перенесу метод draw ()..."  - да. Взяли бы и проверили сами в IDE

Comment: А улучшить вроде ничего и нельзя, этож обычный [DTO объект](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/918871/218293)

Comment: @Anton Sorokin, начнем с того, что у автора изначально не правильный дизайн классов, а переделать через интерфейс или класс не имеет разницы - это раз. Два - у вас точно не правильное представления того, что такое `DTO` и как минимум советую узнать, что такое `POJO`. `DTO` изначально абстрактно был придуман для паттерн для `EJB` и это никакой не `DTO`. Это два обычных класса, не правильно спроектированы автором и все о чем говорят, это только о том, что нужно учить и разбирать ООП.

Comment: Почитай тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/849435/204920

Comment: @raviga спасибо. Да, у автора не до конца DTO, потому что у него есть методы. Но по ссылке которую я прислал правильное описание DTO же?

Comment: @AntonSorokin по ссылке все описано правильно, но классы автора очень далеки от DTO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такие принципы ООП как наследование и полиморфизм, были созданы для того, чтобы решать задачи подобного плана.

```
public class Example
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Shape shape = new Rectangle(...);
      shape.draw();
   }
}

public abstract class Shape
{
   protected String title;
   public Shape(String title)
   {
      this.title = title; 
   }
   public void draw();
}

class Rectangle extends Shape
{

   private int x1, y1;
   private int x2, y2;
   private Color color;
   private boolean visible;

   public Rectangle(String title, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color color, 
   boolean visible) {
      super(title);
      this.x1 = x1;
      this.y1 = y1;
      this.x2 = x2;
      this.y2 = y2;
      this.color = color;
      this.visible = visible;
  }  

  public void draw()
  {
     // next code here 
  }

  // getters setters
}
```

Позже при потребности вы можете создавать и другие классы, к примеру, `Triangle` и т.п. И использовать правильные паттерны проектирования(например `Strategy`), которые работают на полиморфизме и популярны в примерах, как у вас:

```
public void Draw(Shape shape)
{
   shape.draw();
}

void func() 
{
   Draw(new Rectangle(...));
}
```

По этому, учите в первую очередь [ООП](https://www.andiamogo.com/S-OOD.pdf), а потом идите на интервью.

Comment: Метод draw присущ не только классу shape, например если реализуется графический редактор, то помимо того, что инструментом shape можно нарисовать квадрат или треугольник, то инструментом кисть, также можно рисовать.

Comment: @komdosh `brush` это уже инструмент, который может в себе (has a) включать `shape`. Не вижу в этом проблемы

Comment: В `Shape` метод `draw()` - `protected `по идее он должен быть `public` ведь программист-клиент который будет реализовывать этот метод будет смотреть на базовый класс

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov правда. исправил