# Spring RESTful + hibernate многомодульный проект

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

Вопрос следующий!
Мне необходимо создать приложение, состоящее из нескольких модулей:

- authorization (модуль авторизации)
- main (основной модуль)
- directories (модуль со справочниками)
- logging (модуль логирования)

В дальнейшем могут быть и другие модули. Каждый модуль представляет собой автономное **Spring Restful** + **hibernate** приложение (`war` файлик).

Модули должны взаимодействовать друг с другом. То есть, допустим, модуль **main** использует справочники из модуля **directories**.

Вопрос такой, какая существует практика взаимодействия между такими автономными модулями?

 Могу предположить, что модули общаются посредством **rest** запросов, но, тогда если, допустим, мне потребуется получить в модуле **main** справочник городов **city** (из модуля **dictionaries**), то мне в модуле **main** придется хранить класс-сущность **City** и так со всеми сущностями.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы используете maven, опишите данные модули в pom файлах, кто от кого зависит при сборке и т.д. и используйте справочники из City при работе в main. Например основной pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ru.group.example</groupId>
<artifactId>example-parent</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>example parent</name>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
...
</properties>
<modules>
    <module>example-module1</module>
    <module>example-module2</module>
    <module>example-module3</module>
</modules>
<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh-external</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>1.0-beta-6</version> -->
        </extension>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>1.0-beta-6</version> -->
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Затем файл pom.xml например module1 :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <groupId>ru.group.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>example-module1</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.group.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>example-module2</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

module2, по аналогии с первым, у них будет общий перент и свои зависимости. Ну а дальше уже в коде импортируйтесь и используйте, свои классы методы и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

1. Если у вас несколько сервисов, то при rest комуникации им следует передавать не саму Entity -> City, а DTO -> CityDTO, это помогает избежать проблем с сериализацией. [Наглядный пример различия DTO, POCO (POJO) и Value Object](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456623/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-dto-poco-pojo-%D0%B8-value-object)
2. Создайте модуль "common", в котором будут находиться DTO, в том числе и CityDTO, а зетем добавьте на него зависимость модулям "main" (основной модуль) и "directories" (модуль со справочниками).