# Сериализация класса, сгенерированного Entity Framework

Tags: xml, entity-framework, serialize

Добрый день, я использую Entity Framework. Я применил подход DataBase-First и EF создала сущности по таблицам в БД Test, Picture, Question, Answer.
[image: Model DB]

Class Test:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Test")]
public partial class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        Questions = new HashSet<Question>();
    }

    [XmlIgnoreAttribute]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Theory { get; set; }
    public bool IsShowTheory { get; set; }
    public string URLonTheory { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int CountRandomQuestion { get; set; }
    public int CountCorrectAnswers { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PictureForTheory { get; set; }
    public System.Guid GUID { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnoreAttribute]
    public virtual Picture Picture { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Questions"), XmlArrayItem("Question")]
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

Class Picture:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Picture")]
public partial class Picture
{
    public Picture()
    {
        this.Tests = new HashSet<Test>();
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public byte[] Picture1 { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}
```

Class Question

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Question")]
public partial class Question
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int Test { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public virtual Test Test1 { get; set; }

    public Question()
    {
        this.Answers = new HashSet<Answer>();
    }
}
```

Class Answer

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Answer")]
public partial class Answer
{
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsTrue { get; set; }

    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }

    private Answer()
    {
    }
}
```

Мне нужно сериализовать класс Test и все связанные с ним классы в один xml файл. Пытался сделать так:

```
private static void SerializeTest(Test test, string path)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlFormat = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test),
        new Type[] {typeof(Picture) , typeof(Question), typeof(Answer)});

    using (Stream fStream = new FileStream(path,
            FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        xmlFormat.Serialize(fStream, test);
    }
}
```

При попытке сериализации выбрасывается исключение с сообщением

> Cannot serialize member TestSystem.Test.Questions of type System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[TestSystem.Question, TestSystem, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] because it is an interface.

Как правильно сериализовывать сгенерированные EF классы? 
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в двух словах, то нужно использовать промежуточные классы их уже сериализовать для передачи между слоями приложения или между приложениями.

Эти классы, так называемые DTO(data transfer object) классы, не содержат виртуальных свойств или какой-то логики и используются только только для трансфера.

В шарпе есть подход POCO который реализует этот принцип и, вроде бы, даже может сгенировать эти классы, подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd456853(v=vs.110).aspx), а так много полезного про DTO и POCO уже есть на [ru.stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456623/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-dto-poco-pojo-%D0%B8-value-object)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я создал классы TestProxy, QuestionProxy и AnswerProxy, в которые "залил" данные из сущностей EF.
Сериализация прошла без проблем и как я хотел.
За информацию про РОСО отдельное спасибо, не знал про такое. У себя не стал использовать, т.к. база маленькая, но на большом проекте чувствую что без РОСО не обойтись.