# Java. Одни и те же сущности в бэкенде и фронтенде

Tags: java, javafx, rest, frontend, dto

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно организовать структуру приложения.
Приложение представляет собой автоматизацию приходно-расходных операций магазина.
Есть REST-сервис и фронт на JavaFx.
В чем беда: нужно, чтобы фронт был независимым проектом. Но в нем используются Hibernate Entities (такие же, как в бэкенде). Сначала я думал сделать пакет с Entities в виде библиотеки и подключать в два проекта. Но на одном форуме мне подсказали, что для этого нужно использовать паттерн DTO. Почитал про него и особо ничего не понял. Есть проблема с понятием как это сделать.

Т.е., например, пользователь открывает список приходных документов. Допустим, мы их как-то получили с REST-сервиса и отобразили. Если выделить один из документов и нажать "Просмотреть", то должен открыться список товаров в документе. Ну и обычные CRUD-функции, типа добавить товар в документ, удалить, отредактировать...
Вопрос в том, что, например, пользователь создает товар и хочет добавить его в документ. Т.е. мы создаем объект класса `Product` и отправляем на REST этот объект с указанием Id документа, к которому привязать. Но какой в этом смысл, если есть entity класса `Product`. Это приведет к тому, что все поля из пришедшего объекта `ProductDTO` нужно будет скопировать в поля новой entity `Product` и только потом сохранить. На мой взгляд - горы избыточного кода.

Хорошо, допустим, мы хотим только отобразить список документов. По сути, список Entities, типа `List<Document>`. На REST-сервисе переделывать `Document` в `DocumentDTO` и отправлять `List<DocumentDTO>`? Тогда нужно опять же, чтобы и на фронте и на бэке был класс `DocumentDTO`. Почему тогда не сразу entity?

В общем, совсем непонятен паттерн. Если можете, поясните, пожалуйста. Ну или хотя бы укажите, где это нормально описано. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Метки DTO, действительно, раньше не было, а метка frontend была, только в русском варианте - "фронтенд", это же всё-таки ru.SO :)

Comment: Просто TDO не содержит логики и служит просто контейнером для данных, своеобразный голый класс с данными если совсем по простому и без заморочек. А Entity может содержать в себе дополнительную логику или нести перегрузку лишними данными, что может быть нежелательно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456623/Наглядный-пример-различия-dto-poco-pojo-и-value-object.

Comment: Взгляните в сторону Protocol Buffers (protobuf). Там можно удобно описать сущности для обмена между фронтом и бэком.

Comment: Всем спасибо. Вроде немного начал понимать.

Comment: @Virkom варянт удаленый вызов метода, RMI, COBRA но вы можете в итоге потеря один из плюсов JavaFX, проперти(автообновления), точней ваш сервис ничего сам послать не сможет(вроде как), вызовы нужно делать из приложения FX. Или сервером сделать сам FX, а ваш сервис будет вызывать методы обновления и пересылать туда данные

Answer (score 0):

> Это приведет к тому, что все поля из пришедшего объекта ProductDTO
>   нужно будет скопировать в поля новой entity Product и только потом
>   сохранить. На мой взгляд - горы избыточного кода.

Да, действительно, код будет дублироваться. Помочь с рутиной конвертации одного типа в другой могут несколько библиотек, например `BeanUtils` или `Dozer`.

> На REST-сервисе переделывать Document в DocumentDTO и отправлять
>   List? Тогда нужно опять же, чтобы и на фронте и на бэке
>   был класс DocumentDTO. Почему тогда не сразу entity?

На первые 1 вопроса ответ "да". На второй вопрос ответ несколько сложнее. Суть паттерна DTO - в создании **контракта** между сторонами обмена данными. Бэк энд пусть оперирует своими сущностями, фронт энд - какими нибудь полями формы.

Суть в том, что данные, которыми компоненты системы обмениваются между собой собой - одинаковые. И на каждой стороне есть некий адаптер, который приводит DTO к нужному виду (либо в вид сущностей для БД, либо в заполненную форму для сайта).

Возможно, в вашем случае DTO и не нужны, если у вас всего 2 стороны обмена и поток данных простой. Но если данные как то "путешествуют" между несколькими системами - DTO нужен однозначно. Чтобы при изменении одной системы (допустим, какая то система начинает ждать новое поле) не приходилось переделывать все остальные, ограничившись лишь доработкой адаптера соответствующей системы.

Comment: Спасибо большое за информацию.