# mvvm обновление живого списка в View

Tags: c#, mvvm

Внутри модели есть живой список устройств, у каждого устройства есть свои поля. Как оповещать список в VM, чтоб тот обновил View?

Обновление полей в этом списке смог сделать через INPC, но мне кажется это не лучшим вариантом, так как модель захламляется и не удается двоично сериализовать ее.
Я вижу что необходимо написать дополнительную модель к существующим и в ней оповещать об изменениях, но тогда нужно подстроить логику чтоб работала с этими классами, а не с самой моделью.

Модель:

```
[Serializable]
public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Computer> PCList { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Computer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

Логика:

```
public class Logic
{
    private List<Group> _Groups;
    public List<Group> Groups { get { return _Groups; } set { _Groups = value; } }

    // code

    public Logic()
    {
        // code
        _Groups = LoadGroups();
        _Server.Start();
    }

    private void ClientConnectedEvent(object sender, MyArgs e)
    {
        Computer comp = new Computer();
        // code
        _Groups[0].PCList.Add(comp);
    }
}
```

VM:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Groups = new ObservableCollection<Group>(App.Logic.Groups);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Всё просто — вы не должны сериализовать VM, вы должны иметь для этого отдельные классы (которые только для сериализации и будут использоваться и не содержать логики). Ну а VM делайте полноценной — с INPC и прочими удобствами.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я так понимаю я пошел не верным путем, у меня есть View (интерфейс), VM (команды, привязки интерфейса к модели, без какой либо логики) и Model (сами данные и взаимодействие с ними). Тут я должен добавить 4 элемент ModelVM который должен иметь все оповещения и в нем же будет логика приложения?

Comment: Нет, логика приложения должна быть в VM: команды, свойства для привязки + логика. А логика хранения/получения данных должна быть в модели, там же у вас будет и сериализация, т.к. модельные сущностные классы будут без логики. Если у вас модельные классы тоже имеют какую-то логику, то вам надо добавить еще модельные легковесные DTO-классы для сериализации. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/456623/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP Получится что у меня будет одна большая, главная VM содержащая в себе всю логику, оповещения, свойства, и т.д., так же от нее будут разветвляться VM поменьше для взаимодействия с окнами?
Сервер который отвечает за изменение списка устройств (данных) должен находится в модели или в VM и в определенные моменты просто обновлять модель?

Comment: Ну не обязательно одна большая VM, разбейте ее на кирпичики, если нужно. Логика опроса списка устройств будет в модели, а VM пусть ее периодически опрашивает и строит по ней иерархию VM-ных классов.

Comment: @АндрейNOP как правильно построить VM и работу данными теперь я понял, спасибо. Но на моменте работы с списком запутался немного: сервер представляет из себя модель (живой список + набор методов для работы с ним и элементами), VM будет выдавать ему за основу десериализованный список устройств, привязываться к его живому списку (вероятно через ObservableCollection), после чего все манипуляции проводятся в VM ?

Comment: У вас будет в модели класс, например, `Device` (или `DeviceDto`), который вы можете нормально десериализовать. А в VM будет класс `DeviceVM` к которому будет привязываться View, со всеми INPC и прочим. Когда VM опрашивает модель, та ей возвращает список `Device`, и VM на его основе делает себе список уже из `DeviceVM` (`ObservableCollection<DeviceVM>`). Потом когда разберетесь можно будет подключить какой-нибудь маппер (например AutoMapper) и поручить работу по преобразованию модельных классов в Vm-ные ему (ну это уже по желанию, просто чтобы вы знали что есть такая возможность)