# React Native передача объекта в компонент одним свойством

Tags: android, ios, react-native

В компонент React Native можно передавать любой тип данных. Не сильно ли будет тормозить приложение, если в свойство передавать целый объект данных? И не является ли это плохой практикой?

То есть вместо этого

```
<ItemCatalog 
  id={item.product_id} 
  image={item.image} 
  name={item.name} 
  brand={item.manufacturer.name} 
  size={item.extra_field_4} 
  price={item.product_price}
  unit={this.category.unit}
  onPressItem={(id) => navigate('Product', {
    id: id
  })} />
```

вот так

```
<ItemCatalog 
  id={item.product_id} 
  data={item} 
  onPressItem={(id) => navigate('Product', {
    id: id
  })} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> И не является ли это плохой практикой?

Не является, практика хуже - огромное число параметров, везде нужно искать компромиссы.

Исходя из примера, Вы передавали в качестве параметров все поля объекта, теперь передаете сам объект. Вы пришли к `DTO` (возможно):

> Data Transfer Object (DTO) — один из шаблонов проектирования, используется для передачи данных между слоями приложения, либо для передачи данных между различными приложениями. Их можно рассматривать как хранилище информации, единственная цель которого — передать эту информацию получателю.

Ссылки для более глубокого ознакомления:

https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTO
[Наглядный пример различия DTO, POCO (POJO) и Value Object](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456623/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-dto-poco-pojo-%D0%B8-value-object)

---

Насчет скорости при передаче объекта - можете не беспокоиться, объект передается по ссылке, а не копия. Если беспокоитесь о скорости работы приложения, то главная проблема которую нужно устранять - это React Native.

Comment: Я, просто, переживаю о скорости работы мобильного приложения. Но я пришел к мнению оставить так как есть, потому что в объекте `item` гораздо больше данных, чем нужно одной карточке.